# How do I decode a depthTexture into linear space in the [0-1] range in HLSL?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl

I've set a RenderTexture as my camera's target texture. I've chosen `DEPTH_AUTO` as its format so it renders the depth buffer:

[image]

I'm reading this texture in my shader, with `float4 col = tex2D(_DepthTexture, IN.uv);` and as expected, it doesn't show up linearly between my near and far planes, since depth textures have more precision towards the near plane. So I tried `Linear01Depth()` [as recommended in the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-DepthTextures.html):

```
float4 col = tex2D(_DepthTexture, IN.uv);
float linearDepth = Linear01Depth(col);
return linearDepth;
```

However, this gives me an unexpected output. If I sample just the red channel, I get the non-linear depthmap, and if I use `Linear01Depth()`, it goes mostly black:

[image]

**Question:** What color format is chosen when using `DEPTH_AUTO` in the Render Texture inspector, and how do I convert it to linear `[0, 1]` space? Is there a manual approach, like a logarithmic function, or an exponential function that I could use?